# How can I get around caching policy when using Laravel to generate CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, nginx, caching

I am using Laravel to generate files for what would otherwise be inline JS and CSS.

> The web.php configuration is:

```
Route::get('/js/words.js', function() {
    $words = Word::get();

    return response()->view('words', compact('words'))->header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
});
```

When I deploy this to the server initially everything is fine. But then, when I add a simple CSS/JS caching policy to the Nginx configuration, the generated CSS/JS breaks.

> The Nginx configuration is:

```
location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
    expires 30d;
}
```

**Does anybody else do this to avoid inline CSS/JS, and if so, how do you enable caching without breaking the generated files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used it like this

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
   expires 365d;
   access_log off;
   add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

and make sure to restart the nginx server

`sudo systemctl restart nginx`